# Searching for Proofs of Wedderburn Theorem for finite dimensional simple Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, algebras

Hi im searching for proofs of the Wedderburn Theorem for finite-dimensional simple Algebras over a field. I know that there are a lot of proofs of Wedderburns Theorem for finite Divison-Algebras. Im searching for a simple proof not using the Artin-Wedderburn-Theorem for semisimple Rings. I just found two proofs one with Brauers Lemma and one with Rieffels Lemma. 
In searched in algebra-books.Is there a better way for searching?

Comment: For example [here](http://www.imsc.res.in/~knr/14mayafs/Notes/knr_2.pdf), Theorem $10$?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. that helped a lot.