# Module over finite dimensional simple algebra isomorphic to direct sum of minimal Ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, algebras

How can i show that a Left-Module M over a finte dimensional simple K-algebra A, that has finite dimension over K, is isomorphic to a direct sum of an minimal left ideal in A and the number of summands is well defined?

My idea is:
Because of the finte dimension i know that A has a minimal left ideal I. 
So i can define the map $I^{n}\to M,(x_1,\dots,x_n) \to m_1x_1+\dots m_nx_n$. I choose n  to be minimal so the map is injectiv. But is this map surjectiv? I know that M=AM=IAM=IM. But for this map i need a finte set of generators. I know that there is a finite K-Basis in M but is this an I-Basis?

Answer (score 1):

The natural map $\rho\colon A \rightarrow {\rm End}_K(I)$ defining the action of $A$ on $I$  is injective,
since the kernel is a proper two-sided ideal and $A$ is simple. 
But the map is also surjective because of Burnside's Lemma. Hence $A\cong I^{\oplus n}$.

Reference: Lemma 6 and Theorem 7 [here](http://www.imsc.res.in/~knr/14mayafs/Notes/knr_2.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much but is there a more elementary way?

Comment: Maybe I could say that A is a matrix ring over a skewfield by Wedderburns theorem. Then A is semisimple and M is A semisimple A Modul but there is only on class of isomorphic simple modules over a matrix-ring.                                        But i would like to proof it without the theory of semisimple rings.

Comment: But Wedderburn's Theorem would be of the same level. I find Lemma 6 quite elementary. Did you [find](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573702/searching-for-proofs-of-wedderburn-theorem-for-finite-dimensional-simple-algebra) Wedderburn?

Comment: But in lemma 6 you need an algebraically closed field.  Now i find Wedderburn elementary, especially for simpöle rings but I would still prefer something without this theorem.